# How to change preload type of video from none to auto with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I try to change the `preload` type. 
First I set `preload` to `none` in HTML. Then I try to change it via jQuery:

```
<video preload="none" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" playsinline="" muted="muted" loop="" poster="aaM.jpg" class="has_sound">
     <source src="aaM.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

//script

var video_section = $('video');
video_section.attr('preload','auto');
```

But with this code it doesn’t change the `preload` value from `none` to `auto`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add or remove controls attribute from html5 <video> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193957/add-or-remove-controls-attribute-from-html5-video-tag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var video_section = $('video');
  video_section.prop('preload','auto');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work.
    When you use `[0]` or `get(0)` after the jquery selection it becomes like a DOM selection. So it's like

```
document.getElementById('someVideo')
```

Therefore you can go like this

```
$('someVideo')[0].preload="auto";
```